# transpose of a matrix with affinely independent rows

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given an $m$ by $n$ matrix A with real entries, such that its rows, considered as points in $R^n$, are affinely independent.

If we consider the transpose matrix $A^T$, will the rows of this matrix, considered as points in $R^m$, be affinely independent as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not. To give the easiest counterexample, take $m=2$ and $n=4$. Four points in $\Bbb R^2$ can never be affinely independent.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, e.g.
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$